# How to launch the same opencv C++ program that uses a webcam twice on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, ubuntu, webcam

I have a C++ program using openCV that opens a webcam.

The lines that do it are the followings:

```
cout<<"camera initializing\n";
VideoSettings cam(camNum + CAP_V4L);
cout<<"camera initialized\n";
cout<<"Ch3ck c4m3ra is 0p3n3d\n";
if ( !cam.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Could not open reference " << sourceReference << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

I compiled the program and it runs without problems.

However I would like sometimes to launch the same program on Ubuntu18.04 twice with the same cam (whose id is passed as bash argument).
The error I get when launching the second instance that opens the same cam is:

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
Unable to stop the stream: Device or resource busy
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0
```

Of course the code is stopping becasue `cam.isOpened()` is not verified.

The same program (removing `CAP_V4L`) on OSX can be launched many times without any problem.

Why the behaviour is different? And there is any simple workaround to have the same behaviour on Ubuntu?

Comment: Most likely not easily -- generally webcams/cameras are designed to be used by one client at a time. (Kinda makes sense -- how would you deal with 2 programs asking for different sized images at different exposures, for example) One way to work around it would be to have a master program which grabs frames from the webcam and then streams them to multiple clients. You can probably find some existing implementations of that -- search around.

Comment: In a similar C++ application though I can run two instances of the same program that opens the same webcam on OSX. The same does not run twice on Ubuntu.